# How to Create Template File for Parent Page of Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, templates

After creating a custom post type I made a custom template file for the post (`single-customposttypename.php`). So the URL structure would be: `example.com/page/postname`, and  `postname` would be the post that renders `single-custompostype.php` (this works fine).

But what I'm trying to get is `example.com/PAGE` to loop all the posts generated from that custom post type on one page...which it does, but it's unstyled. I tried creating a custom template called `page-customposttypename.php` but that didn't seem to work.

Seems like this should be really simple but I can't seem to figure it out. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: @brasofilo Thanks for the formatting edit. Excuse my noobish stackexchange etiquette, lol.

Comment: That's what I like about the Stack, new things to learn every day ;) When you see a formatting that you like, click [edit], check what's been used, **click `cancel`** and presto, apply elsewhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different ways to implement what you want to do, and both are perfectly valid, depending on your needs:

1. Post-type archive index page
2. Custom page template

### Post-type archive index page

This implementation uses [the WordPress template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) to output the archive index page for your custom post type. For [custom post type archive index pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Post_Types_display), the template hierarchy is:

1. `archive-{posttype}.php`
2. `archive.php`
3. `index.php`

So, if you want a custom layout/markup for the archive index page for your custom post type, create `archive-{posttype}.php`.

The advantage with this implementation is that you *don't have to make any changes to the default query*. You simply output a normal loop, and have all normal `$post` variables, conditionals, and tags available to you, out-of-the-box.

To **view** the archive index page for your custom post type, if you have pretty permalinks enabled, use: `home_url() . '/{posttype}/`, e.g. `www.example.com/{posttype}/`.

### Custom Page Template

This implementation uses [WordPress custom page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) to output a custom-query loop of posts for your custom post type.

This implementation will allow you to display your custom post types on a specific page, e.g. `www.example.com/pagename`, but has several drawbacks:

1. It is more difficult to implement.

   Where `archive-{posttype}.php` is used/displayed automatically by
   WordPress, to use a custom page template, you have to create a
   static page, then assign your custom page template to the page, then
   publish the page.
2. It is more difficult to develop.

   Unlike `archive-{posttype}.php`, a custom query loop in a custom page template does *not* use the default query, and does *not* have all of the normal `$post` variables, conditionals, and tags available.

   You will have to define a secondary query, via `WP_Query()`

   You will have to use a custom loop-instantiation markup.

   You will have to use a workaround if you want to use pagination.

That said, here is a quick-and-dirty custom page template:

```
/**
 * Template name: Custom Post Type Display
 */

get_header();

$cpt_query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'foobar',
    'posts_per_page' => '10'
)
$cpt_query = new WP_Query( $cpt_query_args );

if ( $cpt_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $cpt_query->have_posts() ) : $cpt_query->the_post();
    // Loop output here
    // You CAN use normal post tags here,
    // such as the_title(), the_content(), etc.
endwhile; endif;

// Reset postdata
wp_reset_postdata();

get_footer();
```

(For more detailed answers about using custom page templates to display custom loop queries, and especially for custom query loop pagination, just search WPSE for related questions/answers.)

Comment: Both answers helped, however, this one goes a step further in terms of implementation which actually answered some other questions I had been wondering about. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates): If the custom post type were 'product', WordPress would look for archive-product.php to display the archive of posts.

Comment: Ah, right right! When in doubt, CODEX! Thanks for the link. I will try this and report back.